# Programmatically created UILabel not working in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios6

I programmatically create a few UILabels in my app.  In iOS 5 this code worked fine.
In iOS 6 the labels simply don't seem to appear on the screen.

I don't see any warnings, the code definitely executes, but no label.

I've tried searching for similar issues but can't find anything.  My labels have literally just disappeared.

Any help appreciated.

```
float popUpWidth = 700.0

//Add label
UILabel *label;
label = [[UILabel new] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,popUpWidth,50)];
label.text = @"Notes";
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//Add label to view
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a label twice as wide as the devices screen, and setting a small amount of text to be centered thus causing the text to be off screen. Remember CGRect uses points not pixels. Additionally, I tested your code and had to replace "new" with "alloc" for it to work properly, I suggest you do the same.

The full correct line would be:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,popUpWidth,50)];
```

Comment: The size of the label is correct.  This is on an iPad in landscape mode.  The 'new' was the issue.  Should be 'alloc'.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried to mark it as correct, but it appears to only allow me to mark one as correct.  So when I mark yours correct, the tick on the other answer disappears.  Can I mark two correct somehow?

Comment: Good point.  I had thought the other answer was first as it appears first on my screen for some reason.  But I agree, will mark yours correct as first correct response.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `[UILabel new]` is like calling `[[UILabel alloc] init]` so you should change your code like this:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,popUpWidth,50)];
```